# The verb to be (intransitive or transitive)

Tags: verbs

As far as I know, to be - is intransitive. But how does it happen that it takes a pronoun in the objective form?

This creature can be any one. It can be **you, him, her.**

Or are they not subjects? I mean **you, him, her.**

PS: Sorry, I confused the word "subjects" with "objects".

Comment: "Be" is intransitive. "It" is the subject in your examples, and the pronouns are predicative complements. Incidentally "be" is always an auxiliary verb, even when it's the only verb in the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

"You", "him" and "her" are not objects. They are predicative complements. There are only a handful of verbs that take predicative complements. One of the verbs is the word *be* (and its inflectional forms, namely *is, are, was, were*, and *am*).

Predicative complements can have both forms: objective and subjective. So these are perfectly grammatical:

> It can be **you** 
> It can be **he** 
> It can be **she**

However, the subjective forms are very formal and sound stilted in normal conversation.

Comment: Would this be also correct? "This creature can be he/she"? I don't mean "a he or a she"? I mean it can change into him or her.

Comment: Yes. That would be correct.

Comment: But don't you see the difference? 1 "This creature can be he" = " "He can be this creature" = He is this creature.= This creature is he. 2 The creature can be him. = This creature can become him. (But "He can't be this creature).

Answer (score 2):

The verb **BE** is a linking verb or copula.

The subject of your sentence *It can be you, him, or her* is the dummy *it.*

The highlighted pronouns in your sentence are *Subject complements.*

Comment: Would you say "I want to be her" or "I want to be she"?

Comment: I want to be **her** is right. Not the **she** version.